# Add a Figure in Multicol Environment Latex

Tags: floats

I'm developing my university's TCC model in latex, using overleaf. I need the text in two columns, but I can't add figures to it, even using the \ begin {figure} command
...
\ end {figure}
nor the figure * command. Can someone help me?

this is the code I am currently using.
In the figure 'exemplo.png' is where I having problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[brazil, english]{babel}%linguas utilizadas
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%escolhe a fonte
\usepackage{times}%fonte times
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hhline} % para usar linha dupla na tabela
\usepackage{tabularx} % para igualar colunas
\usepackage{booktabs,chemformula}
\usepackage{multirow}

\geometry{a4paper, left = 2.54cm, top = 2.29cm, right = 2.54cm, bottom = 2.03cm}%margens de acordo com modelo TCC v2018


\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnsep}{7.5mm} %column separation

\usepackage{blindtext} %Automatically generates dummy text.

\title{\textbf{TÍTULO EM MAIÚSCULAS}}
\author {\sc Primeiro Autor^1 \and\sc Segundo Autor^1 \and \sc Assim Por Diante^2}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
          \begin{center}
              \includegraphics[scale = 0.72]{cabecalho.PNG}
          \end{center}
              \vspace{-45pt}%aproxima o texto POSTERIOR da imagem
      \end{figure}

\maketitle
        \begin{center}

        \vspace{-15pt}%aproxima o texto POSTERIOR
              \textit{1.Laboratório, Departamento, Instituto Federal de Santa Catarina\\Chapecó, Santa Catarina, Brasil\\ primeiro.autor@dominio.br, segundo.autor@ifsc.edu.br\\2.  Laboratório de Qualquer Coisa, Depto. de Outra Coisa, Universidade de Algum Lugar\\Cidade, Estado, País\\ AssimPorDiante@universidadealgumlugar.edu.br}
        \end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vskip 2mm
    \selectlanguage{english}
    {\noindent \bf Abstract}: This is where the abstract should be placed. It is a single paragraph providing a concise summary of the material in the paper below. It usually has less than 200 words. It should not be confused with the introduction, must not contain abbreviations, footnotes, references to literature, figures, etc.
    \vskip 1mm
    {\noindent\bf Keywords:} Keyword list, separated by, colons (Maximum of four keywords).
    \vskip 1mm
    \selectlanguage{brazil}
    {\noindent \bf Resumo}:  Este é o lugar de colocar o texto do resumo (um único parágrafo, que é um sumário conciso do trabalho, menos de 200 palavras em geral). Não deve ser confundindo com a introdução, ele não possui abreviações, notas de rodapé, citações, etc.
    \vskip 1mm
    {\noindent\bf Palavras-chaves:} Lista de palavras-chave, separadas por vírgulas (Máximo de quatro palavras-chave)
]

%%Texto
\selectlanguage{brazil}

   \section{Introdução}
            Este arquivo pode ser aberto em todas as versões do Microsoft Office, OpenOffice, e outros editores de texto que suportem abrir arquivos tipo .docx. Para manter a formatação adequada, basta especificar o estilo certo para cada parte de seu artigo. Por exemplo, no cabeçalho acima, todas as partes indicam o estilo correto (entre <>). O estilo deste parágrafo é <Texto> e do título da seção é <Título 1>. Felizmente, você não tem de especificar estes estilos a todo o momento, porque o estilo seguinte é automaticamente escolhido. Os estilos que, de fato, você usará são <Título 1> e <Título 2>, quando você decidir começar uma nova seção ou uma nova subseção \cite{yoshida2000particle}. \\
            A parte principal do artigo deve ser preferencialmente dividida nas seguintes seções: 1) Introdução; 2) Métodos; 3) Resultados e Discussões; 4) Conclusões.
            Na introdução deve ser realizada uma contextualização do problema e da teoria envolvida. No caso, busque um livro e pesquise em base de dados sobre o assunto em questão. Não avance mais que uma página neste item. Pesquise bem sobre o assunto e faça uma boa revisão bibliográfica – não utilize mais que uma página.
\selectlanguage{brazil}
        \section{Métodos}
            Aqui devem ser descritos em detalhes os métodos e procedimentos que foram aplicados pelos autores e que geraram os resultados retratados no presente artigo.\\ 
            Empregue no texto uma linguagem técnica. Pre-ocupe-se com a clareza do texto e sempre que usar termos pouco conhecidos, os defina anteriormente.\\
            O artigo deve fazer uso exclusivamente do Sistema Internacional de Unidades (SI). Os símbolos das unidades das quantidades devem estar em itálico (20mV). Sempre que uma abreviatura aparecer no texto pela primeira vez, a forma completa do nome precede a sigla que deverá estar entre parênteses. Exemplo: a) Associação Brasileira de Ensino de Engenharia (ABENGE). B) Amplificador Operacional (Op-amp, do inglês: operational amplifier).
            \subsection{Figuras e Tabelas}
            Ao inserir figuras observe que a resolução seja alta, de tal forma que não perca informação ao momento de imprimir. Antes de finalizar seu trabalho, imprima ele em papel e verifique se o tamanho das figuras, em especial o texto informativo, esteja legível. 
            Identificar cada figura e tabela por um número sequencial. A identificação da ilustração aparece na parte inferior precedida da palavra designativa (ex.: Fig. 1), seguida de seu número de ordem, do respectivo título e/ou legenda explicativa e da fonte. Dica: Para evitar problemas com numeração de itens no Word, use o menu “referências” - “inserir legenda” e “inserir”- “referencia cruzada”.\\
            A ilustração deve ser apresentada após sua citação no texto. Lembre sempre de colocar as unidades nos eixos dos gráficos e nas tabelas.\\
******%HERE'S THE PROBLEM******
            \begin{figure}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width = 6cm]{exemplo.png}
                     \caption{Caption}
                \label{fig:my_label}
                \end{center}
            \end{figure}
            Na identificação de Tabelas, devem aparecer os seguintes dados: título, cabeçalho, fonte, notas, chamadas. A estrutura da tabela, constituída de traços, é delimitada por linhas. Deve-se separar o cabeçalho do conteúdo por linhas simples. \\
            \begin{table}[H]
                \begin{center}
                    \caption{\\\center DISTRIBUIÇÃO DA ESTIMATIVA DE PERDAS NO PROTÓTIPO}\label{tb:tb1}
                    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
                        \hline \hline
                        \bf Componente & \bf {Perda} \it (W)\\ \hline
                        Diodos ponte&0.88\\\hline
                        Mosfet $M_l$&4.53\\\hline
                        Indutância$L_i$&2.50\\\hline \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{center}
            \end{table}
        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{ref}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you can not use `^1` to add superscripts when in text mode (See `\author{...}`). You can use `\textsuperscript{1}` instead.

Comment: Having resolved that error, the next error message occurs due to the use of `\\\center` inside of a `\caption` command. If you want a linebreak after "Tabela 1:", take a look at the `caption` package.

Comment: Instead of `\sc` in the `\author` command, use `\textsc{...}` or `\scshape`.

Comment: From the `multicols` documentation: "   At  the moment only  page-widefloats (i.e., star-forms) can be used within the scope of the environmen". Therefore, `figure*` should wokr fine. If you want a single column wide image, remove the figure environment and use `\captionof{figure}{your caption text here}` from the `caption` environment.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The starred `\figure*` *is* supported with `multicol`.  It just won't appear on the page on which it is input.  See [Include floated figure in two column environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35703).

Comment: multicol works by using one long column then splitting it into two.  Theoretically it could easily support top  floats in the first column and bottom floats in the second column.  You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530084/i-want-to-wrap-text-only-above-and-below-a-figure-inside-of-a-column interesting.

Comment: if this is a template fro new documents, don't use `\bf` and `\sc` which are not defined by default in latex and have been deprecated since 1993.